# Cannot install Fedora on a G7 Dell

Tags: fedora, boot, system-installation, bios

I am trying to install Fedora with a bootable flash drive that I have created with Rufus on my Dell G7 7700. But the flash drive is not automatically detected. So I went into the BIOS menu to manually "add a boot option". There I found my flash drive, but I must indicate a precise path to a file. But I do not know which file to choose...

P.S.: I have disabled the Secure boot mode.

Edit :[image: Here is the browser I am talking about]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why but I had to change the partition scheme to GPT.

Comment: Changed where? How did it help? Are you saying your BIOS failed to see bootable USB media when your disk was MBR formatted? It's a BIOS bug.

Comment: I had to change it in Rufus while mounting the bootable flash drive.  Indeed, my bios could not see the flash drive when it was MBR formatted.